# Node - How to run a parallel command during a --watch?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I am using webpack to combine all of my .css, .js and .html into one .html file which gets placed in a SVN directory. It then gets copied to a local server via a `copy` command. I have my webpack set to `--watch` so I don't have to consistently re-run the command to get my changes. I am using VS Code.

```
"wpbuild": "npx webpack --watch & npm run copyFile",
"copyFile": "copy C:\\fromLocation\\file.html C:\\toLocation /y",
```

Since my `--watch` doesn't end, the copyFile script never runs. This works if I take out the `--watch` but that would defeat the purpose of what I am trying to do.

**Question:**  How can I get the file to be copied, after every time that it gets re-created? I want to do this with just one command please.

Answer (score 2):

You could give the package [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) a shot.

> Run multiple commands concurrently. Like npm run watch-js & npm run watch-less but better.

`Concurrently` would let you do something like this:

```
"wpbuild": "concurrently \"npx webpack --watch\" \"npm run copyFile\"",
"copyFile": "copy C:\\fromLocation\\file.html C:\\toLocation /y",
```

If `npm run copyFile` is able to watch for files, it should be able to create a file whenever one is created, however if it cannot watch for files, it may run before one is created.

Comment: I've tried this. But copyFile does not seem to get called after each time the file gets recompiled.